# Applying function to multiple files and saving data to data frame row by row?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm using `for` loop to apply several functions to text files in my work directory then write the new files to the directory using `writeLines` function. At the end of each iteration I would like to record the file name and number of rows in one data frame called `d.f`.

I created a data frame using:

```
d.f <- (file_name,number_of_rows)
```

The code looks something like:

```
my_files <- list.files(path="path to my wd")    
for (i in 1:length(my_files) { ..........
.........
.........
a <- readLines(my_files[i], skipNul=TRUE)
.........
.........
# here is the line I tried to add to record the data:
d.f <- rbind(my_files[i], length(a))
}
```

Any suggestions how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_files <- list.files(path="path to my wd")
a <-  readLines(my_files[1], skipNul=TRUE)
d.f <- data.frame(my_files[1],nrow(a))
for (i in 2:length(my_files) { ..........
.........
.........
a <- readLines(my_files[i], skipNul=TRUE)
.........
.........
dummy <- data.frame(my_files[i],nrow(a))
names(dummy) <- names(d.f)
d.f <- rbind(d.f,dummy)
}
```